# What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1-\tan2x)^{\cot x}$?

Tags: limits

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow0}(1-\tan2x)^{\cot x}$$
I see that it has something to do with exp but nothing more.

Comment: Take the logarithm. Can you find $$\lim_{x\to 0} \cot x\cdot \log (1-\tan (2x))\,?$$

Comment: The Maple command $$ Student[Calculus1]:-LimitTutor((1-tan(2*x))^cot(x), x = 0)$$ produces the answer $e^{-2}$ step by step with explanations. See that [link](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples/Calculus1SingleStepping) for info.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Take the natural log inside the limit, replace $\cot$ with $\frac1\tan$, and apply L'hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(1-\tan 2x\right)^{\cot x}=e^{\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\log(1-\tan 2x)}$$

But we have that

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log(1-\tan 2x)}{\sin x}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{2}{\cos x\cos^22x}\cdot\frac1{1-\tan 2x}=-2$$

and since $\,\cos x\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1\;$ , we get that the limit is

$$e^{-2}=\frac1{e^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

As $x\to 0$, $\tan(x) \approx x$
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( 1 - \tan(2x)\right)^{\cot(x)} = \lim_{x\to0} (1 - 2x)^{\frac 1 x} = e^{-2}$$

Comment: That seems to require a more careful argument, somehow.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, I imitated few users here ... I don't have much experience on analysis myself.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Any limit of the form $ \lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} $ where $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x) = \infty$ and can be evaluated as:

$$ \large \lim_{x\to a} f(x)^{g(x)} =  e^{ \lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-1)\cdot g(x) } $$

Comment: You've mixed up $x$ and $a$ here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! Edited.

Comment: @DonAntonio, why do you say so? Agreed this doesn't hold for $f(x) < 0$ but here anyways, $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 1 > 0$, right?

Comment: Oh, @ParthThakkar: I missed the little limit there.: my bad.